# Как сделать выполнение очереди действия при зажатой кнопке не моментальным, а с определенным интервалом на Python

Tags: python

Есть программа, которая фиксирует нажатое положение определенной кнопки клавиатуры, и пока нажатие активно выполняются действия(например стрельба). Как сделать небольшую задержку между выполнением этих повторяющихся действиях. Естественно без постановления на паузу всей программы (time.sleep())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов.

1. Делаем выстрел, запоминаем время - t1
2. Узнаем текущее время - t2
3. Если t2 - t1 > интервала, стреляем, если меньше не стреляем.
   И так в цикле.